# Can we have two mutual foreign key references

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, create-table

If two tables A and B need to have mutual foreign key references, each foreign key constraint can be defined in the create table statements for A and B. I am trying to do this in pgAdmin, but its showing error. I want to just verify is this statement is true or false. I have a doubt that in order to add a foreign key reference in child table. It should have the parent table. Can some confirm this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql - Mutually dependent foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990986/mysql-mutually-dependent-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have mutual foreign key references, but you can't define both of them using only `create table`. The reason is that when you define the first table, the second table doesn't exist yet, so you can't reference it in a foreign key.

```
create table A (id serial primary key, Bid serial references B);

create table B (id serial primary key, Aid serial references A);
```

Returns this error at the create table A:

> Schema Error: error: relation "b" does not exist

And because A failed to be created, the create table B also returns an error:

> Schema Error: error: relation "a" does not exist

Instead, you need another step. First create table A, then create table B with its foreign key reference to table A, then *add* the foreign key to table A. Now that table B exists, you can reference it.

```
create table A (id serial primary key);

create table B (id serial primary key, Aid serial references A);

alter table A add Bid serial references B;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gb9vo1fQy8Jty1pGdn8Q7o/0